# unable to undserstand Class<?> mClass

Tags: android, tinydb

I was reading the documentation of TinyDB -:

```
  TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);
    ArrayList questionsStatusArrayList = new ArrayList<QuestionsStatus>();
    tinydb.putListObject("MyQestionsData", questionsStatusArrayList);
```

for getting back the list they are using -:

```
   public ArrayList<Object> getListObject(String key, Class<?> mClass)
```

What is -: Class mClass . What is expected there?

Comment: Doesn't `Class<?> mClass` mean any class? Like `Type T`

Answer (score 2):

That expects any type of Class. Problably in your example a `QuestionsStatus.class`.

Comment: I have the same question, trying to figure out the exact syntax of what is required.